# How do I prevent all menu items from adding style on:hover?

Tags: html, css

Recently I have noticed that when you are styling menu item on:hover, some properties like **text-shadow**, **color**, **background** and and many others are applied to the menu item that is currently be hovered over.

However, it seems that the **padding** property is applied to all the menu items, not just the menu item being hovered over.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/Bizzet/pen/LEvopq

```
.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    transition: 1s;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
}

.main-navigation a:hover {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

As you can see in Codepen, the text-shadow is applied to a single menu item while the padding is applied to all the elements.

What can I do to prevent this?

I only want one menu item to hover at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

Your `ul li a`'s have a negative margin-bottom initially.
When you hover over an `a`, though, you reset the margin-bottom to 0. This causes the box to grow in size and push the whole nav-bar upwards.

## Insight

The padding is not being applied to all list items. One of the links in your nav boxes is pushing the whole navigation bar up, which gives the *appearance* of applying the padding to all list items.

## Demo

Run this snippet for a demo. The menu-items are black.

```css
header {
  min-height: 10em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  background: green;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.container:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}
span {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: -0.75em;
  display: block;
  transition: all 3s;
}
span:hover {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <ul class="container">
    <li class="item">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <span>there</span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <span>friend</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

## Solution

It should be noted that negative margins are usually not encouraged, unless you want element overlap. If it is necessary, it can be better to set a negative margin on 1 parent element than each individual child.

To hack this particular problem together, just replace this:

```
a:hover { margin: 0; }
```

with this:

```
a:hover { transform: translateY(-70%); }
```

*Keep in mind that you might have to add `-browser-` prefixes to the `transform` rule. [Browser support here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)*

Comment: Thank you for explaining everything in detail. TranslateY is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

The padding is not being applied to all menu items. What's happening is that the height of the parent container is being expanded by the hover effect, and since the other menu items are top-aligned, they raise as well.

Try this:

```
.main-navigation a:hover {
  ...
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYNOKJ)**

Comment: The OP would either need to set a fixed height, or position the links absolutely

Comment: Thanks, this helped me simply understand what was going wrong. It seems the **transform: translateY** is what I needed!